# How do I iterate through Google spreadsheet when column headings are obtained via transpose?

Tags: gdata

I have two Google spreadsheets within one spreadsheet document. The first has a list of names. Each row corresponds to a unique name.

The second document displays a transpose of the first. This means that the names, which were listed row by row in document one, are now displayed as column headings. I achieve this using the following equation:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FirstSheetName!A2:$A)
```

In my python code I attempt to read the row list from the second sheet as follows:

```
spr_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()

worksheets_feed = ... # obtain feed of worksheets
sheet_id = get_sheet_id('SecondSheetName') # method for retrieving the sheet id
sheet_feed = spr_client.GetListFeed(SPREADSHEET_KEY, sheet_id)
```

However, when I attempt to iterate through the lists, I see unexpected results. In the custom dictionary I do not see the transposed headings, which are visible in when viewing the sheet via the google drive UI. Instead, I see many entries with random keys that look like hashes. Some examples are: '_cssly', '_auk5k', '_a832w'.

```
sheet_feed.entry[0].custom.keys() # results don't correlate directly with column headings
```

My question is, what are these strange keys referencing? And how can I obtain the data they are pointing to?

Comment: did you try a cell feed rather than a list feed. I find Cell feed is better for complex spreadsheet data and List feed works well with simple data tables.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar question, and was very much helped by the hint of using GetCellsFeed.

Here's how my code looked:

```
import gdata.spreadsheet.service
import datetime
#http://www.payne.org/index.php/Reading_Google_Spreadsheets_in_Python

username = 'username@gmail.com'
passwd = "password"
spreadsheet_id = "xxxxxxx" #take it out of the url between key= and &

# Connect to Google
gd_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
gd_client.email = username
gd_client.password = passwd
gd_client.ProgrammaticLogin()

#Use this snippet to find the worksheet id given the name of the worksheet
feed = gd_client.GetWorksheetsFeed(spreadsheet_id)
for f in feed.entry:
    if f.title.text == "Worksheet Name":
        worksheet_id = f.id.text.rsplit('/',1)[1]
        print f.title.text, worksheet_id
        break

The interesting bit of code!
cells = gd_client.GetCellsFeed(spreadsheet_id,worksheet_id).entry

d = dict()
keys = []
for cell in cells:
    if cell.cell.row == '1':
        keys.append(cell.cell.text)
        d[cell.cell.text] = []
    else:
        k = keys[int(cell.cell.col)-1]
        v = cell.cell.text
        if k == "Date":
            d[k].append(datetime.datetime.strptime(v, '%m/%d/%Y'))
        else:
            d[k].append(int(v))
```

This will create a dictionary with keys as per the first row and lists of (in this case) integers and dates.  You could also use float(v) for floats or just v if you want the string.